# array length in CAPL using symbolic constants

Tags: capl, canoe

I'm defining an array in CAPL with 'int array[5]'.

It would be useful to define the length of this array using a define, such as it can be done in C:

```
#define LEN 5
int array[LEN];
```

Is there a way to obtain the same result with the tools at our disposal in Vector CAPL language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain similar result use **const** type qualifier.

```
const word LEN = 5;
int array[LEN];
```

You can use different datatype than word (unsigned, 2 Byte), ex int (signed, 2 Byte) ...